# Delphi - Adding onclick to a button created at runtime

Tags: delphi, eventhandler

I have a procedure that creates a `customtitlebar` and `titlebarpanel` at runtime for any form name passed to it.  The purpose of this is to handle the creation automatically for a bunch of different forms without having to worry about the current form control positions.  This code shuffles all controls down automatically so they are not covered by the `titlebarpanel`.

This code works.  Call this procedure from any form's `oncreate` adds 2 buttons to the form titlebar area.

```
procedure CreateTitleBarPanel(fname:tform);
var titlebarpanel:ttitlebarpanel;
    F1button,F12button:tspeedbutton;
    i:integer;
begin
     fname.customtitlebar.enabled:=true;
     titlebarpanel:=ttitlebarpanel.create(fname);
     titlebarpanel.parent:=fname;
     titlebarpanel.Visible:=true;
     fname.customtitlebar.control:=titlebarpanel;
     F1button:=tspeedbutton.create(titlebarpanel);
     F1button.parent:=titlebarpanel;
     F1button.top:=10;
     F1button.height:=fname.customtitlebar.height-15;
     F1button.width:=F1button.height;

     //this is the problem
     F1button.onclick:=how??

     F12button:=tspeedbutton.create(titlebarpanel);
     F12button.parent:=titlebarpanel;
     F12button.top:=10;
     F12button.height:=fname.customtitlebar.height-15;
     F12button.width:=F12button.height;
     F12button.left:=fname.customtitlebar.clientrect.width - F1button.Width - 8;
     F1button.left:=F12button.left - F1button.Width - 8;
     //move all form components down to match the titlebar height
     for i:=0 to fname.ComponentCount-1 do
     begin
          try
             (fname.Components[i] as TControl).top:=(fname.Components[i] as TControl).top+fname.customtitlebar.height;
          except
                //control does not have a top property, so skip it
          end;
     end;
end;
```

My issue is that I want the onclick for the buttons to call another procedure passing in the fname, so eg something like

```
F1button.onclick:=AnotherProcedure(fname);
```

That doesn't work though.  `E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter`
Can anyone explain how I can get this to work?  Button created at runtime, when clicked I want it to call `AnotherProcedure(fname);` (this procedure is the same unit as the `CreateTitleBarPanel` procedure if that helps.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't include a parameter.  `F1button.onclick:=AnotherProcedure;` should work, as your making reference to the method, not calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it exactly as you wrote.

A button's `OnClick` event is a link to a procedure with type `TNotifyEvent`. That means that first of all this procedure must have only one parameter with type `TObject`, and second this procedure must be a method of some object.

If you want to have similar behavior as you wrote - you need to add this method to every form that you pass into `CreateTitleBarPanel()` and assign it to your buttons, or you need to have some global object with your method with specified behavior. Something like that:

```
type
  TMyButtonsClickHandler = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure DoButtonClick(Sender : TObject);
  end;

var      
  MyButtonsClickHandler : TMyButtonsClickHandler;

implementation  

{ TMyButtonsClickHandler }

procedure TMyButtonsClickHandler.DoButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  fname : TCustomForm;
begin
  //Sender must by one of our buttons, make sure that
  if Sender is TSpeedButton then
  begin
    //get form of our button
    fname := GetParentForm(TSpeedButton(Sender), true);
    //calling your functionality with form object as IN param, as you ask
    AnotherProcedure(fname);
  end;
end;

initialization
  //create our global object before any calls
  MyButtonsClickHandler := TMyButtonsClickHandler.Create;

finalization
  //destroy our global object in finalization
  FreeAndNil(MyButtonsClickHandler);

end.
```

When you will have this global object, you can make `F1button.OnClick :=  MyButtonsClickHandler.DoButtonClick;` inside your `CreateTitleBarPanel()` function, and then click on any of these buttons will run your `AnotherProcedure()` with the parent form as the parameter.

Comment: "*and second this procedure must be a method of some object*" - actually, it can also be a `class` method, no object needed. And if you are adventurous, you can even use the `TMethod` record to use a standalone procedure instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you are right. Didn't know that. In this case we can just declare some class without handle life cycle of object, Thanks for adwise.

Answer (score 3):

[`TSpeedButton.OnClick`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Buttons.TSpeedButton.OnClick) is an event handler (inherited from [`Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnClick`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnClick)) and its type is [`TNotifyEvent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent).

Type definition:

```
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```

This means that you have to define a procedure accepting a `TObject` parameter on an object (it may be your form or any other object).
For example:

```
 TMyForm = class(TForm)
 public
   procedure MyOnClick(Sender : TObject);
 end;

...

procedure TMyForm.MyOnClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  
end;
```

Then you'll be able to assign it as the `OnClick` event handler of your button in this way:

```
F1button.OnClick := MyOnClick;
```

Comment: Just to clarify - when the button is clicked on, the procedure's `Sender` parameter will point at the button itself, and the `Self` pointer inside the procedure will point at the object which the procedure belongs to.